# Can't save or download data to USB memory stick

Tags: usb, chmod

I normally use Windows on my desktop but like to experiment with Linux. I've tried several distros and different desktops. I'm currently using Ubuntu with Cinnamon but my problem applies to all other distros/desktops. I boot from a SSD sata drive after disconnecting my windows boot drive.

Namely, it is a problem with using a USB memory stick/thumbnail. I use Linux to securely download csv files as zips or rars and for security want to download to the usb device.

The problem is that I am only allowed to save to the SSD sata drive I booted from. And having saved, no archiver will unpack the file to the usb.

As a Windows user, I am used to having access to all drives and folders. Allegedly, Linux thinks this is dangerous so restricts access. This amounts to throwing the baby out with the bathwater. With millions/billions of Windows users out there, surely it is obvious that Linux has gone overboard?

Anyway, rant over, I would appreciate some help here. I believe I need to use a chmod command on the usb stick but that this isn't as simple as it sounds. Am I right? I am happy to do basic command line stuff in Linux, as it like the old DOS days when I started in computers. So any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

OK sorry. I have issues opening archive files on a USB stick and also setting the stick as the default download folder in Tor browser. Using Files I can add, open, read and write files to the stick, but no archiver will work on the zip or rar files, complaining they lack permission.

I sometimes succeed by using a chmod command but it doesn't stick nor can I change permissions in Files by right clicking and editing Permissions. I also tried to follow instructions for creating a new group etc but got lost as the instructions seems to be outdated.

This seems a common issue in Linux and forums are full of advice. None seem to work for me! I want to make a single USB stick fully read/writable for all software permanently. It is formatted ext4 by the way, not Fat anything..

Comment: I'm not sure if understand the problem. Are you saying that If you download a file on a linux OS that you booted from an SSD you are unable to unzip it on the same SSD and copy the unziped file to the USB?

Comment: "*Allegedly, Linux thinks this is dangerous so restricts access.*" No, it usually means that you are simply using it wrong. Not sure how, as the rant includes insufficient useful detail. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1473574/edit) to show us EXACTLY what you are doing that doesn't work. Complete input and output, copied/pasted into your question above.

Comment: Sounds like like another "Windows Fast Boot F'd my USB disk" problem, but there's too much rant, too much premature diagnosis, and not enough information. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting